# Munkres' Proof of Well Ordering Property

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, induction, proof-explanation, intuition

In Munkres' *Topology* the proof for the Well-Ordering Property is stated as follows:
[image]

- I'm having confusion with the first and second underlined part: "Let A be the set of all positive integers n for which the statement holds." *Isn't this the very statement that we are trying to show is true in this subproof* ? Can you please restate this in a different way because I feel as though it might be ambigious??
- When he says "this set" in the last underlined part does he mean the set $C \cap \{1,..., n \}$ or the set $A$?
- And I'm sorry to put it so generally but *what is the key idea behind the subproof*; is it to show that intersection between the set of the first $n$ integers and any subset of it has a least element? I don't see how such an intersection should imply the existence of a least element.

Thanks in advance guys, I hate asking to clarify so many little points but this one just ain't clicking for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm having confusion with the first and second underlined part: "Let A be the set of all positive integers n for which the statement holds." *Isn't this the very statement that we are trying to show is true in this subproof* ? Can you please restate this in a different way because I feel as though it might be ambigious??

No, this statement is merely a *definition*.  The symbol $A$ is being defined to refer to the set of $n$ such that the statement holds.  We don't yet know that the statement holds for all $n$, and we're just collecting all the $n$ such that it *does* hold into a set and calling that set $A$.  We're not asserting that the statement ever actually does hold; maybe $A$ is empty.

The role of $A$ is that we now want to prove $A=\mathbb{Z}_+$.  That means that every positive integer is an element of $A$, or in other words that the statement holds for every positive integer $n$.

> When he says "this set" in the last underlined part does he mean the set $C \cap \{1,..., n \}$ or the set $A$?

He means $C \cap \{1,..., n \}$.  The statement $n\in A$ by definition means that any nonempty subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has a least element.  Since $C\cap \{1,\dots,n\}$ is a nonempty subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, it therefore has a least element.

> And I'm sorry to put it so generally but *what is the key idea behind the subproof*; is it to show that intersection between the set of the first $n$ integers and any subset of it has a least element? I don't see how such an intersection should imply the existence of a least element.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.  The overall goal is to prove that if $D$ is any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$, then it has a least element.  We do this using the following observation: if $n\in D$, then the least element of $D$ must be less than or equal to $n$.  So if we find the least element $k$ of $D\cap \{1,\dots,n\}$, then $k$ is actually the least element of all of $D$.  Indeed, for any $d\in D$, if $d\leq n$, then $k\leq d$ since $d\in D\cap\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $k$ is the least element of $D\cap\{1,\dots,n\}$.  And if $d>n$, then obviously $k\leq d$ since $k\leq n$.

So using this idea, we only need to prove that $D\cap \{1,\dots,n\}$ has a least element.  Now we rename $D\cap\{1,\dots,n\}$ to $C$ and think of $C$ as just some arbitrary nonempty subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  So what we want to prove now is that any nonempty subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has a least element.  This is what the subproof is proving, and it does so by induction on $n$.

Comment: Great answer. I 'd be obliged if you could have a quick view at my answer which attempts only to supplement yours and let me know if you feel my analysis is correct.

Comment: Also the proof is notable in that it never uses the fact (not proven yet) that n<n+1. Munkres glosses over many things saying that they are "obvious" and I don't doubt that they are for Munkres yet many students might hastily agree that the are obvious albeit for the wrong reasons. Even in your own answer the fact when you say that "obviously k<=d since k<=n" it took me some time to satisfy myself that indeed I can rigorously show that $k\lten$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @eric-wofsey is excellent. I also spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure that out. If I may add something though. Munkres is structuring the proof in two parts for a reason:

The first part uses the principle of induction to prove a statement (namely the existence of a smallest element) for a certain class of **finite** (in size) subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$: the $\{1...n\}$ family of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ which are indeed finite in size for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. These sets not only have a specific shape (they consist of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$, i.e. no "holes") but, more crucially, they are finite in size. You are not able to use induction to prove that statement if it were extended to sets of that shape having infinite size (actually only one such shaped set of infinite size exists, $\mathbb{Z}_+$ itself, which is what you are trying to prove in the first place!).

The second part uses what was proven in the first part (with induction) to extent this statement (the existence of a smallest element) to **arbitrary** subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ which may be of infinite length. For the second part induction is not used.

Indeed it is possible to prove, with induction, in one go (no two parts), that every finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ has a smallest element. However, that statement alone is narrower than what Munkres is trying to prove here. Namely Munkres is trying to prove that this statement is true for **every** subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ (finite or infinite). And if you were to try and use that statement as a stepping stone for the actual statement Munkres is trying to prove you will realize that the statement is actually *broader* than what is needed (if it's meant to be used as a stepping stone). This is becuase you need that stepping-stone statement not necessarily for finite in size arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ but simply (less demandingly) for finite in size subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ of the shape described above ($\{1...n\}$). In other words Munkres uses, for the first part of his proof, the narrowest possible stepping stone that allows him to reach the second part and thus complete the intended proof.